# Python: collect data from multiple lines at a time and print the results in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, cucumber

I'm using cucumber on my project and to keep track of all our steps I've written a small script in Python that seeks out the feature files in a certain directory and get me the steps based on the gherkin keywords.  Below or above these steps we're trying to put a description of what each step does.
When I collect all these steps I want to be able to also print the instructions for the respective steps.

```
import os

searchPath = "somePath"
dirs = os.listdir(searchPath)
givenLine = []
whenLine = []
thenLine = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchPath):
newFile = open("filePath", "w")
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".feature"):

        with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as featureFile:
            linesOfFiles = featureFile.readlines()

            for lineOfFile in linesOfFiles:
                if "Given" in lineOfFile and "#" not in lineOfFile:
                    givenLine.append(lineOfFile.strip())
                    continue
                if "instructions" in lineOfFile:
                    givenLine.append(lineOfFile.strip())
                    continue
                if "more instructions" in lineOfFile:
                    givenLine.append(lineOfFile.strip())

                if "When" in lineOfFile and "#" not in lineOfFile:
                      givenLine.append(lineOfFile.strip())
                      (same code as above)

                 if "Then" in lineOfFile and "#" not in lineOfFile:
                     thenLine.append(lineOfFile.strip())
                     (same code as above)


for linesToWrite in givenLine, whenLine, thenLine:
 newFile.writelines("\nStep: " .join(list(sorted(set(linesToWrite )))))
```

Running the code above gives me the results but the list is not preserved.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand your question so I can probably not provide the right answer. But can you not just:

```
searchPath = "somePath"
dirs = os.listdir(searchPath)
myLines= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchPath):
    newFile = open("filePath", "a")
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".feature"):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as featureFile:
        linesOfFiles = featureFile.readlines()

        for lineOfFile in linesOfFiles:
            lineDict = {}
            if "Given" in lineOfFile and "#" not in lineOfFile:
                lineDict["givenLine"] = lineOfFile.strip())
                continue
            if "instructions" in lineOfFile:
                lineDict["instructionsLine"] = lineOfFile.strip()
                continue
            if "more instructions" in lineOfFile:
                lineDict["moreInstructions"] = lineOfFile.strip())

            if "When" in lineOfFile and "#" not in lineOfFile:
                  lineDict["when"] = lineOfFile.strip())
                  (same code as above)

             if "Then" in lineOfFile and "#" not in lineOfFile:
                 lineDict["then"] = lineOfFile.strip()
                 (same code as above)
             myLines.append(lineDict)

for linesToWrite in myLines:
    if linesToWrite["givenLine"]: 
        newFile.write(linesToWrite["givenLine"])
    if linesToWrite["instructionsLine"]:
        newFile.write(linesToWrite["instructionsLine"])
    #etc....
```

You also dont have to this:

```
linesOfFiles = featureFile.readlines()
```

This is enough:

```
for lineOfFile in featureFile:
```

Also to make your live easy, you can open two files with "with open":

```
with open('inputfile', 'r') as inputFile, open('outputfile', 'a') as output:
```

Comment: hi, no i can't i can't just write the instructions because they are part of the list that i'm collecting.
the question is that i'm collecting a list of items.  the items exist on different lines (but  below the other) in different files.  when i collect the list then when i print this list to file i want the list to remain in order

Comment: thanks, i will implement some of these changes and see what happens

Comment: Ah! like that. You can use modulo or a dictionary. I will edit the answer

Comment: I changed my answer, not sure if it directly works because I just typed it quick. But to give inspiration and a solution.